# pythonw.exe processes not quitting after running script

Tags: python, process, python-idle

Every time I restart the shell or run a script and instance of pythonw.exe*32 is created.  When I close out of IDLE these processes don't go away in the task manager.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `python.exe` instead of `pythonw.exe`?

Im pretty sure this is the intended default behavior for the window python interperter (pythonw.exe).

If its a .pyw file, just right click "Open With..." and use python.exe

Comment: It looks like I only get the issue when I pull the script into IDLE.  When I click on the script to run it I think its running normally.  So the interpretor doesn't shutdown the processes that it generates even after it shuts down?

Comment: Is there a way to change the default shell/interperter that IDLE uses for other scripts from pythonw to python?  I havent used IDLE in years.

Comment: No, it looks like you can't change it.  However, I was able to fire up PyScripter and it is able to abend pythonw.exe when it closes.  I guess I won't worry about the issue if PyScripter is a better editor.  However, I'll try to see if there is a way I can report this bug.  Thanks!

Comment: Anytime, also, check out notepad++, I do a lot of my python scripting in it.  And it can run the scripts just like IDLE can.